# Rename files to match filenames in another folder

Tags: powershell

I have 2 directories.

```
D:\test\get\f

D:\test\set\f
```

Inside `get` folder and `set` folders there are equal amount of files. All files in `set` are the same (it's a common image file duplicated multiple times to match the number of files in `set` folder).

My question is, how do I rename all files in `set` folder same as in `get` folder?

e.g.:

BEFORE

**get folder**

```
apple.jpg
mango.jpg
lychee.jpg
```

**set folder**

```
123.jpg
12!.jpg
asdasd.jpg
```

---

AFTER

**get folder**

```
apple.jpg
mango.jpg
lychee.jpg
```

**set folder**

```
apple.jpg
mango.jpg
lychee.jpg
```

Comment: how are you creating the `set` folder?  why not solve this problem then instead of after the fact?  some ideas come to mind, but would be very specific and easily broken...so more info will help.

Comment: @KoryGill Thanks. I just manually copy and paste the same image file to match the number of files in `set` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example which is unoptimised and assumes best case. It shows the basic steps of iterating through files in a path, getting file names and renaming files.

```
$names = @()
$getPath = "C:\Temp\get"
$setPath = "C:\Temp\set"
Get-ChildItem $getPath |
    Foreach-object{
    $names += $_.Name
}
$i = 0
Get-ChildItem $setPath |
Foreach-object{
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $names[$i]
    $i++
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting an error. `ForEach-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'RemainingScripts'. Cannot convert the "=0" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock"`

Comment: Ok could be your version of powershell. Try changing that line to: [int]$i = 0